# How to add spaces between 32 bit binary number

Tags: binary, output, mips, mars-simulator

I am getting a 32 bit output in Mips and I need to break it into a separation of 5 bits. Could someone please provide code?

Ex: I need the output 00000000000000000000000000000000

to be 00 00000 00000 00000 00000 00000 00000

I really have no idea where to start, please help. Thank you.

Comment: anything anded with a one is itself.   anything anded with a zero is zero.

Comment: How does that help me add spaces?

Comment: You have to isolate each bit as you print them out yes?  How do you plan to isolate the bits?  Start with code that can print them out without the spaces then simply add the spaces.